# Como conseguir o texto da caixa para compartilhamento?

Tags: javascript, html, script

Bom pessoal, boa tarde. eu nunca fiz curso e agora estou apanhando para aprender rs. Bom é o seguinte, eu copiei estes códigos pela internet, e tentei criar uma página legal, do qual tivesse: Campo para editar um texto pré pronto, botão para copiar o texto pronto, e em seguida, gostaria de colocar um para compartilhar no whatsapp, porém gostaria que: no compartilhamento, saísse o conteúdo igual o do campo da edição. nem que para isto, o usuário seja forçado a copiar o campo de edição. Bom! Se alguém puder me ajudar e salvar nesta, serei grato. Obrigado!!

Código da página atual:

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<!--
    Stellar by HTML5 UP
    html5up.net | @ajlkn
    Free for personal and commercial use under the CCA 3.0 license (html5up.net/license)
-->
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TRAVEL TUR</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/main.css" />
        <noscript><link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/noscript.css" /></noscript>
    </head>
    <body class="is-preload">


                    <!-- Main -->
                    <div id="main">

                <!-- Content -->
                            <section id="content" class="main">
                                <span class="image main"><img src="" alt="" /></span><h2><b>HOPI HARI - HORA DO HORROR 2019</b></h2><p align="Justify">SUA COMISSÃO: 32,00 R$</p>
                                <script>
  function copiarTexto() {
    var textoCopiado = document.getElementById("link");
    textoCopiado.select();
    document.execCommand("Copy");
    alert("Texto Copiado: " + textoCopiado.value);
  }
</script>
<div class="col-12">
<textarea name="link" id="link" placeholder="Enter your message" rows="12">
1ª Edição 2019
Datas: 10/08/2019 e 11/08/2019

Central de atendimento e televendas
                        </textarea>
</div>
<button onClick="copiarTexto()">COPIAR TEXTO PARA DIVULGAÇÃO PRÓPRIA</button>

<br><br><br>
<style>
        .whatsapp-share-button{
            display: inline-block;            
            width: 40px;
            height: 40px;
            margin: 5px;
            background-size: 100% 100%; /* ou 'contain' */
            background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;base64,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"); /*Base 64 Icon by Xinh Studio*/
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-position: center;
        }
    </style>



   <a href="" id="whatsapp-share-btt" rel="nofollow" target="_blank" class="whatsapp-share-button"></a>

    <!-- Você pode colocar este script num arquivo externo -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //Constrói a URL depois que o DOM estiver pronto
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
            //conteúdo que será compartilhado: Título da página + URL
            var conteudo = document.textarea; 

            //altera a URL do botão
            document.getElementById("whatsapp-share-btt").href = "https://api.whatsapp.com/send?text=" + conteudo;
        }, false);
    </script>



                        <br><br><br>


                </section>      


            </div>

        <!-- Scripts -->
            <script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="assets/js/jquery.scrollex.min.js"></script>
            <script src="assets/js/jquery.scrolly.min.js"></script>
            <script src="assets/js/browser.min.js"></script>
            <script src="assets/js/breakpoints.min.js"></script>
            <script src="assets/js/util.js"></script>
            <script src="assets/js/main.js"></script>
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>



    </body>



</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Sobre o copiar texto você pode:

Adicionar um id ao botão no html:

```
<button id= "copiarTexto" >COPIAR TEXTO PARA DIVULGAÇÃO PRÓPRIA</button>
```

E criar uma função que durante o click você pega o texto:

```
     $('#copiarTexto').click(function (){
      var textoCopiado = $('#link').val();
        alert("Texto Copiado: " + textoCopiado);
     });
```

Já sobre o Whatsapp você pode seguir a mesma logica e ao botão do whatsapp coloca um id, e cria uma função para enviar o texto para API do whatsapp.